# Shearing only working on the 2 axis I don't want

Tags: modeling

I am making some sort of underground subway inspired by a blender guru tutorial, and I used f-spy to mark out the axis etc. and that worked fine when I imported it in. I positioned a plane and extruded it up. There was a turn in the subway so I want to shear the end of the extruded plane. When I shear something, it always says, in the information in top left, that I can shear it in the x or y axis, as you can see here.
[image]
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmqJr.jpg)
Is there any way of shearing on the z axis? I have come across this issue many times before.

Obviously I could just rotate it, like [image]
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMxQz.jpg), but the rotating creates this tapered effect. I would like to do it by shearing if that's possible.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the *Shear* tool axis will be the one of the view, for example if the view is this one, the X and Y axis will be these ones:

[image]

So if you keep the default *Orientation* and shear on the X axis, the view will be the axis and the vertices will move along the view's X axis, like this:

[image]

But you can also choose to shear on the *Global, Local* axis, etc... You need to choose the *Orientation* in the *Operator* box. In this box, the *Axis* will be the rotation pivot axis, the *Axis Ortho* will be the axis along which the vertices move, the *Offset* will be the amount of units they move.

[image]

In your case you can either put your view on top (7) and shear on the Y axis, or stay in user view, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to shear, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> right away, and in the *Operator* box, switch the *Orientatio*n to *Global*, *Axis > Z*, *Axis Ortho > Y*.

Comment: Thanks @moonbots if I wanted to shear it the way I wanted, how would a alter the settings so I could do that?

Comment: you're right my answer is not completely accurate, I'll edit

Comment: Thanks! Works well now.